# Firebase onDataChanged called a lot of times (without updates) and sometimes with null values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following json tree in my firebase app

```
--ashWoYViS3SbHtBhLpvStRleBl13
----items
-------- -KxDDW1FYMUOxea5w5ii
------------- description: "gggh"
------------- name: "gggh"
```

ashWoYViS3SbHtBhLpvStRleBl13 is the userId, obtaineid with FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser().getUid();

And -KxDDW1FYMUOxea5w5ii is the key for an item, obtained with the push function before inserting the item in the json tree.

There are more items under the items node, this is only a sample.

Then I want to read all the items to show them in a list in my app. I do the following:

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Item> items= utils.convertChildrenToList(dataSnapshot, Item.class);
            getView().setData(customContexts);
            getView().showContent();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            getView().showError(databaseError.toException(), true);

        }


    };


    Query query = database.getReference("/ashWoYViS3SbHtBhLpvStRleBl13/items")
            .orderByKey();
    query.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

At this moment there are 5 items in the list, and after setting the listener with addValueEventListener, I expect to receive the result in onDataChanged only  once. What really happens is that I receive infinite calls to onDataChanged every few seconds. The first time the snapshot has the 5 items. The second time the snapshot is empty (null). The third time the snapshot has again the 5 items, and so on, in an infinite loop.

The database is not being updated, because of that I don't understand why I'm becoming more than one callback in onDataChanged. The data is always there, and I don't understand also why the snapshot's value is sometimes null

If I use addListenerForSingleValueEvent instead, then I receive only one result in the callback "onDataChanged". Sometimes the snapshot value is null, sometimes the snapshot has the 5 elements. In any case, it does not solve my problem.

I tried with many versions of the Firebase sdk, from v11.0.2 to firebase 11.4.2, and it happens in all the versions.

The only way to solve the problem I found, is the following.

Instead of registering the listener for the path

"/ashWoYViS3SbHtBhLpvStRleBl13/items", I register a listener for the path

"/some_prefix/ashWoYViS3SbHtBhLpvStRleBl13/items" (and obviously, I save the data using the same prefix too).

Then all works as expected, that is, I receive only on result in the callback "onDataChanged". The snapshot is not null, and I receive the next callbacks only when the data under the items node is really changed.

Or if I use addListenerForSingleValueEvent, then I receive only one callback with all the elements in the node "items".

May you say me what I'm doing wrong here? (because I don't want to use the prefix before the user id).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds pretty weird. Did you [enable disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) by any chance?

Comment: I tried with and without disk persistance with the same result :(

Comment: The only way I can imagine this happening is if your disk cache is out of sync with your server-side values and you're getting one and then the other. Try removing the app completely, and then reinstalling it after you've stopped using disk caching. That should give you a fresh state to start with (iirc).

Comment: I tried to remove the app from Firebase and I created a new one. Same happens...  :(

Comment: You are probably calling addValueEventListener method multiple times with freshly created new listener objects. Be sure to not call addValueEventListener multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you want to make a query make the fetched false to make sure that onDatachange read the method but when the method inside the onDataChange want to call onDataChange with accident can't have access because your fetched is true then.
For exemple when you make insertion in onDataChange the method will call them self other time without you calling them.

```
Boolean fetched = false;

ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (fetched == false) {
            fetched = true;
            List<Item> items = utils.convertChildrenToList(dataSnapshot, Item.class);
            getView().setData(customContexts);
            getView().showContent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        getView().showError(databaseError.toException(), true);

    }
};


Query query = database.getReference("/ashWoYViS3SbHtBhLpvStRleBl13/items")
        .orderByKey();

fetched=false;
query.addValueEventListener(listener);
```